# Refreshing a MKMapView when the user location is updated or using default values

Tags: ios, annotations, refresh, mkmapview

I'm trying to refresh my map view and load new data from the server when the device acquires the user location.
Here's what I'm doing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
    mapView.delegate=self;
    [self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];
    [self refreshMap];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    //this is to avoid frequent updates, I just need one position and don't need to continuously track the user's location
    if (userLocation.location.horizontalAccuracy > self.myUserLocation.location.horizontalAccuracy) {
        self.myUserLocation = userLocation;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = { userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude };
        [theMapView setCenterCoordinate:centerCoord zoomLevel:10 animated:YES];
        [self refreshMap];
    }
}

- (void)refreshMap {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
    //default position
    NSString *lat = @"45.464161";
    NSString *lon = @"9.190336";
    if (self.myUserLocation != nil) {
        lat = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myUserLocation.coordinate.latitude] stringValue];
        lon = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myUserLocation.coordinate.longitude] stringValue];
    }
    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://myserver/geo_search.json?lat=%@&lon=%@", lat, lon];

    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    [url release];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
```

I also have a - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data, to create and add the annotations.

Here's what happens:
sometimes I get the location after a while, so I already loaded data close to the default location.
Then I get the location and it *should* remove the old annotations and add the new ones, instead I keep seeing the old annotations and the new ones are added anyway (let's say I receive 10 annotations each time, so it means that I have 20 on my map when I should have 10).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In refreshMap, before the removeAnnotations line, check if self.mapView is nil.

Comment: It's not nil, this is what I get:
<MKMapView: 0x584f790; frame = (0 0; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x584f940>>

I can't even test properly because I only notice this problem on a real device and not in the simulator... Is the code logically correct though?

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem.  Maybe it's something with how the annotations are added or in viewForAnnotation.

Comment: Here's how I add annotations, inside a for cycle (relevant parts):
`UserAnnotation *UserAnnotation = [[UserAnnotation alloc] initWithLocation:theCoordinate];
    UserAnnotation.title = [single objectForKey:@"address"];
    UserAnnotation.userID = [single objectForKey:@"id"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:UserAnnotation];`

I can't see anything wrong here either... :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok this might be a little long but it worked for me and I really do hope it will help you.
This is from an app that is used to share different traffic status reports between drivers.

I had this problem also, I tried to load annotations from a server, then delete them and reload the annotations array to the map every time the user sends an annotation to the server himself/presses the "refresh" button/every 1.5 minutes - so that he will always have the current set.

So I thought it might have something to do with the time interval that it takes to load the new annotations from the server, or with the array itself, later I realized it might also be connected to the way the entire code was organized and that maybe some things just got in the way/timing of others.

What I did is basically moving the `[self.map addAnnotations:AN ARRAY OF ANNOTATIONS]` command to the main thread and the whole loading process to the back, I also used a temp array instead of "self.map.annotations" to delete the current annotations, it worked ok afterwards so I just left it like that :), though I'm not a world-class expert (not even close) and I'm sure others might have a more professional and efficient solution, code sample:

```
//this is in viewDidLoad, it kicks off the whole process

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(retrieveAnnotationsDataFromServer) withObject:self];

//this is the method for loading data

    -(void)retrieveAnnotationsDataFromServer
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
        //code for loading..
        NSURL *URL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://YOUR SERVER NAME HERE"];
        NSString *result=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:4 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];
        [parser setDelegate:self];
        [parser parse];

    //Inside the parser delegate i take each element of the report and store it in a mutable array so that i could create the annotations later (report title, report description/subtitle, report location longitude and report location latitude)

        [pool drain];
        NSLog(@"retrieveannotatinsdatafromserver pool drained");
    }

    //Now, in this case the last thing that will happen before the pool is drained is that the parser`s "didEndDocument" method gonna be called, so this is where I delayed the loading like this:

    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
    {
        NSLog(@"parser - document ended, creating annotationsArray");
        NSLog(@"this is the size of RA Array:%d",[self.recievedTitles count]);
        for (int i=0;i<[self.recievedTitles count];i++)
        {
            //RC=recieved coordinate
            //RA=recieved annotation
            CLLocationCoordinate2D RC;
            RC.latitude=[[self.recievedLatitude objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
            RC.longitude=[[self.recievedLongitude objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
            if([self.recievedTitles objectAtIndex:i]==nil)
                continue;
            Annotation *RA=[[Annotation alloc]initWithCoordinate:RC andTitle:[self.recievedTitles objectAtIndex:i] andSubTitle:[self.recievedSubTitles objectAtIndex:i]];

    //the "self.AnnotationsArray" is an array i use to always hold the most current set retrieved from the server        
    [self.AnnotationsArray addObject:RA];
            [RA autorelease];
            NSLog(@"RA %d inserted",i);
        } 
        NSLog(@"Data retrieving ended, loading annotations to map");
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addAnnotations) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];

    }

    //this method was only defined so that i could apply it in the main thread instead of in the background like the whole loading process.. I'm sure it can be done better.

    -(void)addAnnotations
    {
        [self.Map addAnnotations:self.AnnotationsArray];
        NSLog(@"annotations loaded to Map");
    }

    //now we have retrieved them from the server for the first time, the reloading and refreshing part comes next, this method is called any time the user press refresh, sends a report to the sever, or automatically every 1.5 minutes:

    -(void)refreshMap
    {
        NSArray *annotationsToDelete=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.AnnotationsArray];
        [self.Map removeAnnotations:annotationsToDelete];
        [annotationsToDelete release];
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(retrieveAnnotationsDataFromServer) withObject:self];
    }
```

Please do comment on my answer since I will also be very happy to learn a less complicated way of solving this matter.

I think most of these type of problems would have been solved if there was a way to "wait until done" when using background threads, because now what happens is that the code continues to run forward before the whole process of downloading-parsing-creating annotation-loading to map process is actually finished.